# Create 1d array from 2d array's sub objects using [filter, map, some, reduce etc]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have an object as below:

```
Response{
  result:[{products:[o1,o2,o3]},{products:[o5,o7,o8]},{products:[o11,o12,o13]}]
}
```

how can I create an array of all the product objects o1, o2 ... using functional programming (filter, map, some, reduce etc)?

the output should be:

```
outArray = [o1,o2,o3,o5,o7,o8,o11,o12,o13]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use combine [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this purpose:

```js
const products = [{products:[1,2,3]},{products:[5,7,8]},{products:[11,12,13]}];
const result = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], products.map(item => item.products));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const data = {result:[{products:['a','b','c']},{products:['a','b','c']},{products:['a','b','c']}]}
const res = data.result.reduce((a, {products}) => {
  a.push(...products);
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

A little less verbose alternative that still uses `map` and the `spread` operator.

```js
const init = [
  {products: [1, 2, 3]},
  {products: [5, 7, 8]},
  {products: [11, 12, 13]}
];

const result = [].concat(...init.map(x => x.products));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and join together to get desire output

```
let result =[{products:['o1','o2','o3']},{products:['o5','o7','o8']},{products:['o11','o12','o13']}];
let data = [result.map(function(o){ return o.products})].join(',').split(',');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.prototype.flatMap.

```js
const data = [{products: ['o1','o2','o3']}, {products: ['o5','o7','o8']}, {products: ['o11','o12','o13']}];
console.log(data.flatMap(p => p.products));
```